# How to update a table in such a way that its structure remains the same but all the data gets modified?

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have table `EMP1`. It has attributes `EMP_ID, NAME and SALARY`. I have inserted data into it using `INSERT` statement.
Another table `EMP2`. It also has same structure as `EMP1`. But data are different.
Now I want data of `EMP2` should be there in `EMP1`. The data of `EMP1` should be deleted.
Point is the structure of both table is same. Data is to be shifted from `EMP2` to `EMP1` in which original data of `EMP1` gets lost because there is no further requirement of data of `EMP1`.

Comment: How about doing it in two steps i.e. (step 1) delete Emp1 (step 2) Insert into Emp1 values (Select * from Emp2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Delete from EMP1 using below:

```
Delete from EMP1;
```

To insert into EMP1 from EMP2 use below:

```
Insert into EMP1 Select * from EMP2;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM EMP1;
INSERT INTO EMP1 SELECT * FROM EMP2;
COMMIT;
```